# Google Cloud Functions bucket.upload()

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to archive pdf files from remote websites to Google Cloud Storage using a google function triggered by a firebase write.

The code below works. However, this function copies the remote file to the bucket root.

I'd like to copy the pdf to the pth of the bucket: `library-xxxx.appspot.com/Orgs/${params.ukey}`.

How to do this?

```
exports.copyFiles = functions.database.ref('Orgs/{orgkey}/resources/{restypekey}/{ukey}/linkDesc/en').onWrite(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    const params = event.params;
    const filetocopy = snapshot.val();
    if (validFileType(filetocopy)) {
        const pth = 'Orgs/' + params.orgkey;

        const bucket = gcs.bucket('library-xxxx.appspot.com')
        return bucket.upload(filetocopy)
            .then(res => {
            console.log('res',res);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log('err', err);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let me begin with a brief explanation of how GCS file system works: as explained in the [documentation of Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork), GCS is a flat name space where the concept of directories does not exist. If you have an object like `gs://my-bucket/folder/file.txt`, this means that there is an object called `folder/file.txt` stored in the root directory of `gs://my-bucket`, i.e. the object name includes `/` characters. It is true that the GCS UI in the Console and the `gsutil` CLI tool make the illusion of having a hierarchical file structure, but this is only to provide more clarity for the user, even though those directories do not exist, and everything is stored in a "flat" name space.

That being said, as described in [the reference for the `storage.bucket.upload()` method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload), you can specify an `options` parameter containing the `destination` field, where you can specify a *string* with the complete filename to use.

Just as an example (note the `options` paramter difference between both functions):

```
var bucket = storage.bucket('my-sample-bucket');

var options = {
  destination: 'somewhere/here.txt'
};

bucket.upload('sample.txt', function(err, file) {
    console.log("Created object gs://my-sample-bucket/sample.txt");
});

bucket.upload('sample.txt', options, function(err, file) {
    console.log("Created object gs://my-sample-bucket/somewhere/here.txt");
});
```

So in your case you can build a string containing the complete name that you want to use (containing also the "directory" structure you have in mind).

Comment: I am glad I could help! If the answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer so that the community sees it solved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**filepath --> local machine file storage path**

```
 await bucket.upload(filepath, {
      public: true,
      gzip: true,
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
      },
    });
```